# Alias hostname and file path

Tags: linux, apache-2.4, redirect, rewrite, alias

Is it possible to mask the hostname with an Alias and variables?

For example:

I would like to call http://easyNameToRemember/path/to/file

instead of:

http://uglyServerName:8000/the/real/path/to/file

Basically, 'easyNameToRemember' would hold the servername, port, and static API path.

Comment: Alias and cnames only work for hostnames , no ports included, you could try an alias+http redirect to get an easier way for users to reach your server.

Comment: are you per chance searching for something like https://yourls.org ?

Comment: you are mixing two different things. The first thing you are asking for is a DNS A entry or CNAME for your ugly server name. and the second if you want to "hide" a non-typical server port, you would need to place a reverse proxy at the front.

Comment: The answer may depend if you want this to work only from your machine or if you want to do it for everyone (worldwide).